# Jquery Ajax TinyMCE

Tags: php, ajax, tinymce

I have a dynamically generated [link list](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aexternal_link_list_url) from MySQL table for TinyMCE.  This works OK showing all links in the table.  Now I'm trying to pass a value via ajax to the php file that generates the list of links to narrow the query based on the sub-discipline:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#sub_discipline").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: "../scripts/tiny_mce/lists/link_list.js.php",
      type: "post",
      data: {
sub_discipline : $('#sub_discipline').val()
},
      success: function(data){

      }
    });

});
}
);
</script>
```

Problem is that the list of links is not now showing in TinyMCE, probably because the value isn't being passed.  I can get results with link_list.js.php passing the value in the URL string, so something else is happening.  Either the ajax call above is wrong, or TinyMCE loads the list of links when the editor loads and the list can't be updated afterwards.

FYI, in case this can help others, link_list.js.php which works just fine creating the list of links for TinyMCE:

```
<?php Header("content-type: application/x-javascript"); ?>

<?php
require_once('../../../connection/connect.php');
mysql_select_db($database, $connection);

$sub_discipline = $_POST['sub_discipline'];

$query = "SELECT link_title, url FROM link WHERE sub_discipline_fk = '$sub_discipline'";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

$links = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result)){
     $links[$row['link_title']] = $row['url'];

}



$o = null;
$count = count($links);

$i = 1;
foreach($links as $text => $url){
    $o .= sprintf(('["%1$s", "%2$s"]'),

    $text,
    $url

    );

    if($i < $count)
    $o .= ',';
    $i++;
}

?>

var tinyMCELinkList = new Array(

<?php echo $o; ?>

);
```

Link list is added as an option in the tinyMCE.init:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "print,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,bullist,numlist,|,formatselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,|,ltr,rtl",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Skin options
        skin : "o2k7",
        skin_variant : "silver",


        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        external_link_list_url : "../scripts/tiny_mce/lists/link_list.js.php",
        external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

});
</script>
```

Comment: how do you try to get the link list into tinymce?

Comment: See edit...tinyMCE.init config

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your questing correctly you are getting no data on POST from the tinyMCE when it is running in textarea mode...

try adding tinyMCE.triggerSave();

```
  $("#sub_discipline").change(function(){
      tinyMCE.triggerSave();
$.ajax({
```

Comment: Thanks, but saving the contents of a TinyMCE instance is not the problem.  The problem is getting the external link list to update when I pass a value to the php script which genertaes the list.  It could be that the ajax call is wrong or that TinyMCE loads the link list on init and it can't be refreshed.  Not sure which.  The php script which generates the list doesn't have a problem if I just pass a value in the url manually...